# Configuration Issues with SQLSRV for PHP for MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, wamp

I am installing a configuration with WampServer 2.4:

```
- Windows 7 64-bit sp1
- WampServer 2.4 64-bit
- PHP 5.4.3 64-bit (came with the WampServer)
- Apache 2.4.4
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client 64-bit
- Microsoft SQLSRV 3.0 (php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll, php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll and they are put in c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/
```

And I edited the C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini with the lines:

```
- extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/"
- extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
- extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

And I restarted all the services from Wamp.

But I still couldn't see the SQLSRV section from phpinfo -- and of course my connection test program failed.

What might have gone wrong?

Can anyone help?

Comment: First make sure php is showing you any errors,  so please include the following in a php file that you can execute as a test.  ini_set('display_errors','1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');
error_reporting (E_ALL);

Comment: Also,  with extension failing to load,  It is often very simple to see when running the cli  php.exe as it displays erros by default as popups (just double click on php.exe).  A common issue with sqlsrv driver is no having the sql native client installed.

Comment: I did get the following errors: 

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12>php -a
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.
4.12/ext/php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: I also made sure that the Microsoft SQL Server Native Client was installed (as it showed in the Programs and Features with version 9.00.3042.00).

Comment: Last bit of info: From phpinfo, it showed ThreadSafe is On.  That was why I chose the ts.dlls.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your issue is because you are using (or WAMP has given you)  64bit php,  where as your sqlsrv driver is most likely 32bit.

Your solution is to switch to a 32bit version of php (The benefits of running in 64, are pretty much non existent anyway unless you need larger data types), or to recompile the sqlsrv driver in 64bit (Likely more trouble than it is worth).

Try a WAMP 32 bit version.  http://www.wampserver.com/en/#wampserver-32-bits-php-5-4

Also if Apache and my-sql are of no consequence to you (they are just a web sever and and an sql database) you can install a WISP PHP Stack in a breeze using the web platform installer.  http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: You are right.   I'm using just Apache and PHP in 32bit with SQLSRV and it is now working.

Comment: @Tiger Glad it helped!  You need 15 rep to up vote you should be able to accept the answer though.

Answer (score 6):

For those of you using a 64bit version of PHP, the unofficial dll files linked below will work:

http://robsphp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html

I am using 64bit WAMP on a 64bit Windows Server and was about to call it quits before I found those DLL files. It's odd that the official DLLs don't work with 64bit PHP, but I'm glad I at least found a solution.

Comment: Thanks for posting this link as an answer. It saved my day!

Comment: I've been looking for hours, and the x64 dll was the good answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using just Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4 in 32bit with SQLSRV 3.0 and it is now working.  Note that the Thread Safe is set to Yes, thus SQLSRV ts.dlls should be used.  It was a struggle.  Hope this helps others.